# Date will not go to Mysql database c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have written the code below to upload information to my database, however I keep getting the following error:
**Input string was not in a correct format.**

Code to upload information:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        da.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO petinfo(Gender,Name,Age,Bills,FoodCost,Weight,DateAdopted,username,species,breed) VALUES (@Gender,@Name,@Age,@Bills,@FoodCost,@Weight,@DateAdopted,@username,@species,@breed)", cs);

        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Gender", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = petGender.Text;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = petName.Text;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Age", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = petAge.Text;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Bills", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = petVet.Text;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@FoodCost", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = petFood.Text;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Weight", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = petWeight.Text;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DateAdopted", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = petRescued.Text;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userName.Text;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@species", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = petSpecies.SelectedValue;
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@breed", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = petsBreed.SelectedValue;


        cs.Open();
        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cs.Close();
    }
```

Would it be possible to have a look at this and see if you can spot anything wrong?
Thanks

Comment: I realise my typo in the question name.

Comment: Your `AddWithValue()` is wrong.  Look at the parameter names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This:

```
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Age", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = Convert.ToInt32(petAge.Text);
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Bills", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = Convert.ToInt32(petVet.Text);
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@FoodCost", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = Convert.ToInt32(petFood.Text);
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Weight", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = Convert.ToInt32(petWeight.Text);
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DateAdopted", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value =Convert.ToInt32( petRescued.Text);

da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@species",petSpecies.SelectedValue);
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@breed",petsBreed.SelectedValue);
```